# Unrecognized selector issue when displaying facebook highscores in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

I want to display a table of high scores, user name and facebook profile picture for a users friends who are playing a game using a UITableView. I have a facebook singleton class that I use to manage all the facebook code. I keep getting the following error when trying to access the table. The log is:

```
-[FacebookManager tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16f1d790
2014-11-14 14:24:43.000 MyApp[2964:938911] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FacebookManager tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16f1d790'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x29a9ec1f 0x37249c8b 0x29aa4039 0x29aa1def 0x299d3df8 0x1b00a9 0x1328a3 0x13224d 0x132d35 0xc7c73     0x11d555 0x11dec7 0xf132d 0x2cf8e317 0x2cf87be1 0x2cf5e3dd 0x2d1d1c29 0x2cf5ce39 0x29a65377 0x29a64787 0x29a62ded 0x299b1211 0x299b1023 0x30daa0a9 0x2cfbd1d1 0x167353 0x86c90)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please see the relevant code below.
The method that handles the display of the table (which is in another class):

```
-(void)scoresAndMore {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
[[FacebookManager sharedFacebookManager].myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[[FacebookManager sharedFacebookManager] tableView:[FacebookManager sharedFacebookManager].myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

The table code in the FacebookManager class:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];


[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu/scores?fields=score,user", kuFBAppID] parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    if (result && !error)
    {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in [result objectForKey:@"data"])
        {
            NSString *name = [[dict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSString *strScore = [dict objectForKey:@"score"];
            NSString *profilePictureID = [[dict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString *profilePicture = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/picture?width=80&height=80&redirect=false",profilePictureID];
            NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",profilePictureID];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
            NSLog(@"The URL is %@.  The image URL is %@", url, image);
            NSLog(@"This message is in the UITableViewCell and will hopefully show the name %@ and the score %@ along with %@ as the profile picture URL.", name, strScore, profilePicture);

            // DID NOT WORK - cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", image]];
            // DID NOT WORK - cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", profilePicturel]];

            cell.imageView.image = image;//[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url]];

            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %@", strScore];

        }
    }

}];

return cell;
}
```

in the init of the FacebookManager singleton class

```
self.myTableView.delegate = self;
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well you seem to be calling `[tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` on your facebook manager at this line

```
[[FacebookManager sharedFacebookManager] tableView:[FacebookManager sharedFacebookManager].myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Is your facebook manager a delegate of your UITableView .Make sure your facebook manager implements this method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath {
}
```